# Removing lines from files having duplicate date time values.

Tags: parsing, awk, sed

I am working on parsing a file as follows. I see a duplicate line for "ver."=3 and 5 because there is only 1 second difference (Mon Jan 15 08:24:02 vs Mon Jan 15 08:24:03) software prints it twice. 
Also, of you see line for "Ver."5 "Complete Time" has one second difference. I would like delete lines which has rest of the fields matching in the line except "Time" or "Complete Time" column has difference of 1 or 2 seconds.

```
Loc ID   Img Name               Ver.   Time                    Complete Time
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ssfad_fs TINT_PAP_1516048511     0    Mon Jan 15 20:35:13 2018 NA
ssfad_fs sfad_jpg                1    Mon Jan 15 18:24:02 2018 Wed Jan 17 18:24:02 2018
ssfad_fs sfad_jpg                1    Mon Jan 15 16:24:02 2018 Wed Jan 17 16:24:02 2018
ssfad_fs sfad_jpg                2    Mon Jan 15 12:24:03 2018 Wed Jan 17 12:24:02 2018
ssfad_fs sfad_jpg                3    Mon Jan 15 08:24:02 2018 Wed Jan 17 08:24:02 2018
ssfad_fs sfad_jpg                3    Mon Jan 15 08:24:03 2018 Wed Jan 17 08:24:02 2018
ssfad_fs sfad_jpg                4    Mon Jan 15 04:24:02 2018 Wed Jan 17 04:24:02 2018
ssfad_fs sfad_jpg                5    Mon Jan 15 00:24:03 2018 Wed Jan 17 00:24:59 2018
ssfad_fs sfad_jpg                5    Mon Jan 15 00:24:03 2018 Wed Jan 17 00:25:00 2018
ssfad_fs sfad_jpg                6    Sun Jan 14 20:24:03 2018 Tue Jan 16 20:24:02 2018
```

Expected O/P

```
Loc ID   Img Name               Ver.   Time                    Complete Time
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ssfad_fs TINT_PAP_1516048511     0    Mon Jan 15 20:35:13 2018 NA
ssfad_fs sfad_jpg                1    Mon Jan 15 18:24:02 2018 Wed Jan 17 18:24:02 2018
ssfad_fs sfad_jpg                1    Mon Jan 15 16:24:02 2018 Wed Jan 17 16:24:02 2018
ssfad_fs sfad_jpg                2    Mon Jan 15 12:24:03 2018 Wed Jan 17 12:24:02 2018
ssfad_fs sfad_jpg                3    Mon Jan 15 08:24:02 2018 Wed Jan 17 08:24:02 2018
ssfad_fs sfad_jpg                4    Mon Jan 15 04:24:02 2018 Wed Jan 17 04:24:02 2018
ssfad_fs sfad_jpg                5    Mon Jan 15 00:24:03 2018 Wed Jan 17 00:24:59 2018
ssfad_fs sfad_jpg                6    Sun Jan 14 20:24:03 2018 Tue Jan 16 20:24:02 2018
```

When I try `#cat junk1.jnk |sort -uk 3,3` command it deletes third line as well which has same Ver.1 number but different times. I want to keep that line. Please help.

Comment: what if the difference is 5 seconds?

Comment: What have you tried? StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Edit your Q to show your best attempt at coding a solution to your problem. Sorry, but requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour] (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck

Comment: What about `Sun Dec 31 23:59:59` and `Mon Jan 01 00:00:01`?

Comment: only two seconds' difference is fine not 5 seconds or more.

Comment: @shellter I tried sort -uk 3,3 as well as sort -uk 3,3n but removes the other lines as well.

Comment: ALso, I tried  <code> awk '!uniq[$1 FS $2 FS $3]++' </code> which comes closer only problem is it deletes third line.

Comment: you can combine mutiple fields as a key and specifiy character offsets to only sort/uniq by `hr:mm` (and not `:ss`). something like `sort -u -k3 -k 7.1-5` Hm.. can't remember the exact syntax. AND versions of sort features vary by OS, so check you `man sort`. In the future, this sort of Q should be on https://unix.stackexchange.com OR https://superuser.com. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I'll keep that in mind it was my first post. Thank you!

Comment: @Cyrus in case of Sun Dec 31 23:59:59 and Mon Jan 01 00:00:01 it should return only one line.